# In a hash, can we have three keys combined together that point to one value?

Tags: perl, perl-hash

I have a doubt in the below hash declaration:

`%metadataHash` is a hash

```
line 1: $metadataHash->{"name"} = $name;
line 2: $metadataHash->{"type"} = $Type;
line 3: $metadataHash->{"student"}{$file}{"math"} = "/$file";
line 4: $metadataHash->{"student"}{$file}{"phy"} = $phy;
line 5: $metadataHash->{"student"}{$file}{"chem"} = $chem;
```

In line 1 and line 2, it is clear that keys ("name", "type") and values ($name, $Type).

But in line 3,

- can we have three keys `{"student"}{$file}{"math"}` combined together that point to one value?
- In line 3, are they combined together in such a way considered as one key or three different keys?

Comment: Re "*`%metadataHash` is a hash*", Not quite. In `$metadataHash` is a reference to a hash, and `%$metadataHash` is a hash. Same goes for `$metadataHash->{"fastq"}` and `$metadataHash->{"fastq"}{$file1}`, incidentally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$metadataHash->{"fastq"}{$file1}{"read1"}` is shorthand syntax for `$metadataHash->{"fastq"}->{$file1}->{"read1"}`.

It deals with hashes where a value is a reference to another hash.

---

To explain with a demonstration:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $foo = {};

$foo->{a}{b}{c} = 1;

use Data::Dumper;

print Dumper($foo);
```

Gives:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'a' => {
                   'b' => {
                            'c' => 1
                          }
                 }
        };
```

Comment: Now your example is similar to mine. It refers to a hash of hash. One key refers to another hash and the second key "d" refers to a value. Initially, I assumed that all the elements in the hash need to be of similar type. Can I have another key having a value of array?

Comment: Yes, the value can be anything. Read [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html#MORE-ELABORATE-RECORDS) and [Nested Data Structures in *Modern Perl*](http://www.modernperlbooks.com/books/modern_perl_2016/03-perl-language.html#TmVzdGVkRGF0YVN0cnVjdHVyZXM). The key can be only a string by default, but see [perlfaq4](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-can-I-use-a-reference-as-a-hash-key%3f).